# Python - assign class variable pointer to instance method

Tags: python

I have a class and I want to reassign a certain method to an hidden one of the same class.
In my case I have a generic filter that I want to assign to a specific implementation.
I'd like to have the `func_map` as a class attribute instead of an instance attribute because it seems more logic. How should I do that?

```
class MyClass:
    func_map = {"eq" : __eq_filter}
    def set_filter(self, func):
        self.filter = MyClass.func_map[func]

    def filter(self, value):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __eq_filter(self, value):
        return self.attribute == value
```

Comment: @PaulRooney you're right, I edited the code but that's not my issue. The problem is what to place in the dictionary as `{"eq" : __eq_filter}` complains about `eq_filter` being undefined

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the built-in *@staticmethod* decorator, which, according to the docs, allows to bound a method to the class instead of to the instance (*Transform a method into a static method*):

```
class MyClass:
    func_map = {"eq" : __eq_filter}
    def set_filter(self, func):
        self.filter = func_map[func]

    def filter(self, value):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @staticmethod
    def __eq_filter(self, value):
        return self.attribute == value
```

Check the docs for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Comment: staticmethod is more like a standalone function but inside a class. A static method should not have a self parameter. There is classmethod which provides the class as a parameter.